# Lisp libraries for drawing lines and graphics

Tags: graphics, 3d, lisp, line

I would like to be able to draw basic graphics in common lisp. I should only need to draw lines, however I need 3-Dimensional visualization. I have four factors which guide my decision:

1. What library should I use/where could I find out which library I should use?
2. Does common lisp have 3-Dimensional support for drawing lines?

This question has multiple parts because they are all factors as to what I should ultimately use. I should mostly be drawing lines however I need 3-dimensional capabilities!

Thanks so much and let me know if you need more information!

**EDIT** I added the constraint that I need 3-Dimensional capabilities for drawing lines and I took out the "opinionated" questions.

Comment: Web integration **and** draw lines? The input/output library in Common Lisp can be used to produce SVG data.

Comment: I just fixed my question, please re-open. I need lots of advices.

Comment: ANSI Common Lisp has no support for graphics. This is platform specific. All decent Lisp implementations have an efficient foreign function interface (FFI) with which you can call just about any ABI in the system, regardless of how convoluted are the parameter passing conventions and their associated memory management.

Comment: What do you mean by ABI?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I removed my now off topic answer (Non CL). A comment on sds' answer will attract his attention to the changed question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Since the functionality you are asking about is pretty basic, I suggest [CLX](http://www.cliki.net/clx); since you edited to require 3d capabilities, I would suggest [cl-opengl](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-opengl/).
2. I am not sure what you mean by "package manager" exactly, but you might like [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/).
3. Common Lisp is the answer. I am not sure what the question is. :-)
4. Again, it is not clear what "web integration" is, but there are many packages for CL which generate HTML and do other "web" stuff.

Comment: I modified the question due to new developments I would to be able to draw lines in 3-dimensions. I got Quicklisp. Let me know if you have any more ideas. Thanks!